# C# Adding PC to AD domain group

Tags: c#, active-directory-group

Trying to add a hostname to a domain group, and I'm getting the exception `There is a naming violation`.

I've seen several accepted answers covering this exact thing and as far as I know my syntax is correct.

```
try
{
    DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://aa.bbbbb.com/CN=Group,OU=Application,OU=Groups,OU=US,DC=aa,DC=bbbbb,DC=com");
    string hostname = "CN=" + SystemInformation.ComputerName;
    DirectoryEntry add = de.Children.Add(hostname, "Computer");
    add.CommitChanges();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Group join failed" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + ex.ToString());
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was - I needed to pass the Distinguished Name, rather than just the hostname... that should have been obvious, if I had actually read the MSDN doc... Also, `de.Children.Add()` may be a valid method to accomplish this (it was an accepted answer on SE, for .Net 3.5 IIRC), but I used `de.Properties["member"].Add()` to accomplish it.

Updated source code for any Googlers out there:

```
private void DoStuff(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (Process addgroup = new Process())
    {
        string hostname = Environment.MachineName;
        AddMemberToGroup("LDAP://aa.bbbbb.com/CN=Group,OU=Application,OU=Group,OU=US,DC=aa,DC=bbbbb,DC=com", hostname);
    }
}

private void AddMemberToGroup(string ldapString, string host)
{
    try
    {
        DirectoryEntry de = new DirectoryEntry(ldapString);
        string distHost = GetDistinguishedName(host);
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(distHost))
        {
            de.Properties["member"].Add(distHost);
            de.CommitChanges();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Distinguished Host Name returned NULL");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Group join failed" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + ex.ToString());
    }
}

private string GetDistinguishedName(string compName)
{
    try
    {
        PrincipalContext pContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain);
        ComputerPrincipal compPrincipal = ComputerPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pContext, compName);
        return compPrincipal.DistinguishedName;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Failed to get the Distinguished Hostname from Active Directory" + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + ex.ToString());
        return null;
    }
}
```